# Why isn't there a predefined zero division exception in C++?

Tags: c++

It is well-documented in the `ISO C++` standard (I am using ISO C++17) that the result of dividing an integer by 0 is undefined. This can also be seen from the exclusion of a zero division exception in the list of predefined exceptions available in the `<stdexcept>` header:

```cpp
namespace std {
    class logic_error;
    class domain_error;
    class invalid_argument;
    class length_error;
    class out_of_range;
    class runtime_error;
    class range_error;
    class overflow_error;
    class underflow_error;
}
```

While I understand that the callee function can just check if the divisor is 0 and throw a `domain_error` or `overflow_error`, I am wondering what could be the possible reasons for not having a predefined zero division exception.

Comment: The standard library defines those exceptions that are used by the standard library. For your custom functions you can define custom exception types

Comment: @utg.tdawg Are you asking about why there is no specific exception-type for this, or why "const auto y = 1 /x;" does not throw an exception on divide by 0?

Comment: One of the explicit design constraints that guided development of the first C++ standard (ratified in 1998) was minimising incompatibility with C.   In C, division by zero produces undefined behaviour (that was the case in C because different hardware platforms natively do different things on division by zero, and are incompatible with each other).   Changing division by zero to produce an exception instead would have introduced a major incompatibility with C (since C does not support exceptions).

Comment: Because division by zero is usually Undefined Behaviour in C++. We don't want to pay for check if `divisor==0` on every single division to throw exception.

Comment: The behavior for integral types is undefined. Also see : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#:~:text=Dividing%20a%20non%2Dzero%20number,NaN%20and%20FE_INVALID%20is%20raised.)
*2) The result of built-in division is lhs divided by rhs. If rhs is zero, the behavior is undefined.*  The behavior for floating point numbers is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is two-fold. First, the standard library does not define a `division_by_zero` exception because there is no function in the standard library that would throw that exception. The standard library defines exceptions that are used by the standard library. If you need more you can define them.

Next, you might ask why no function in the standard library does throw a `division_by_zero` exception. There are functions of which one might expect it. For example [`std::modulus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/modulus) when instantiated as `std::modulus<int>`. This

```
 std::modulus<int>{}(4,0);
```

invokes undefined behavior, it does not throw an exception.

C++ tries to make you not pay for what you do not need. Often that means that you need to add the bit you want extra. To illustrate what I mean, consider the following example:

```
  void foo(int a,int b) {
        for (int i =0; i < a; ++a) bar ( std::molulus<int>{}(a,b) );
  }
```

It the function would check whether `b` is `0` or not, it would do so in every single iterarion. That is clearly unecessary.

It is much simpler to add such check yourself, rather than to opt out of an existing check:

```
 void foo_safe(int a,int b) {
       if (b == 0) throw my::division_by_zero{};
       for (int i =0; i < a; ++a) bar ( std::molulus<int>{}(a,b) );
 }
```

Looks good no? But lets take it one step further:

```
 void moo() {
      int b = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i<10000; ++i) { foo_safe(i,b); }
 }
```

Um... Now `foo_safe` is safe, but inefficient. In the loop in `moo` the function `foo_safe` makes exactly the same check 10000 times. That is inefficient.

The moral of the story is that extra checks is for user code, not for library code. If you do want a `division_by_zero` exception being thrown, then only you can know where best to perform that check.

Answer (score 7):

(Almost) none of the core language constructs ever throw exceptions (except `throw` of course). The only exceptions to the rule is `new` which may throw a `std::bad_array_new_length`, `dynamic_cast` which explicitly has a throwing and non-throwing form and `typeid` which may throw `std​::​bad_typeid`.

Throwing an exception is a costly operation and one of the primary reasons to use C++ in the first place is performance. It wouldn't make sense to force programs to do null value checks each time there is a division and then throw an exception. If someone wants that, they can wrap that in their own function to use instead of the built-in division operator.

In the exceptions listed above, the operation itself is already costly, so that throwing an exception is acceptable.

The core language must be as performant as possible. Everything else can be done in library functions if so desired.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, but the purpose of `std::modulus` is specifically to turn the `%` operator into a function object, just like similar classes do for all other operators. It is explicitly not supposed to change the semantics.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks. "In the exceptions listed above, the operation itself is already costly, so that throwing an exception is acceptable." - can you share how do you get an intuition on what the cost of an operation is? For example, it isn't obvious to me that subscripting a vector is a lot more costly than a division operation (which therefore justifies having a predefined `out_of_range` exception).

Comment: @utg.tdawg To understand the cost of operations you'll need to understand (at least roughly) how they are implemented: Accessing a vector element is typically just a single `mov` instruction with the location calculated by adding the index on the base pointer. If you add a bounds check, you'll have to introduce a branch and in one side of the branch an exception (which calls out to the C++ runtime library to unwind the stack -> a lot to do).

Comment: @utg.tdawg On the other hand `new` is already costly because it calls an allocator to allocate memory which typically is a rather complicated task and can itself already throw with an allocation failure. `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` use RTTI which is already rather complex.

Comment: sorry for the noise. I'll delete my comments. Decided to write an answer to provide a second viewpoint. This answer is fine as is.